# Facebook comment counter not working

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using facebook comment plugin with my php dynamic website. The comment box is working fine but the facebook count is not working it always shows zero comments.

I use this in index.php

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I use this on the page with the comment box

```
<fb:comments-count href="http://mywebsite.nl/news/<?=$news['ID'];?>.html"></fb:comments-count>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you specifing href to your fb:comments element as well?

Answer (score 1):

Does the url in the `href` above match the url given in the `<meta property="og:url" ... />` tag for the page? The one in the `og:url` tag is the one Facebook will associate the comments with.